# Populating a dropdownlist on change of other dropdownlist by calling code behind method using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using `Asp.Net/C#` , I need to fill a dropdownlist on change of another dropdownlist , I could have done it using `SelectedIndexChanged` event by setting `AutoPostBack` Property to `True` of the first dropdownlist , but I have a password textbox which gets cleared on postback , so that solution was not feasible.I decided to use `jquery ajax` to call my `code behind method` , but I am using this approach for the first time so I cant figure out how do I go about this.Here is what I have tried so far but it is not working for me.

```
$('#ddlDivisionName').change(function() {
        alert('j');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/CreateAccount/CreateAccount.aspx/BranchNameFill",
            data: "{'index':1}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                alert('ok');
            }
        })
        return false;
    });

[WebMethod]
        public static string BranchNameFill(int index)
        {

            ddlBranchName.Items.Clear();   
            IEnumerable<BRANCH> br;
            br = (from b in dt.BRANCHes
                  where b.DIVNO ==index
                  select b);
            for (int i = 0; i < br.Count(); i++)
            {
                ddlBranchName.Items.Add(br.ElementAt(i).NAME.Trim());
            }





        }
```

Comment: it will  most like  not work this way is it even possible to access controls from a webethod easiest way is to create a string with options like html  populate it with your options return in from webmethod and  append it to your drop down list

Comment: @COLDTOLD Ya I understood that I will have to pass an array or something similar and then using jquery I will have to populate dropdownlist , is it ?

Comment: yes you will need to return in from your webmethod and then when you have data just populate your list using jquery

Comment: @freebird these may help you http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-Cascading-DropDownList-using-jQuery-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a simple example I hope it helps you somehow

```
   [WebMethod]
        public List<BRANCH> BranchNameFill(int index)

        {

             br = (from b in dt.BRANCHes
                      where b.DIVNO ==index
                      select b);


            return br.ToList();

        }

    ajax client 
    function getCars() {
        $.ajax({   
          type: "POST",
          url: "/CreateAccount/CreateAccount.aspx/BranchNameFill",       
          data: "{'index':1}",       
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",        
          dataType: "json",        
          success: function(response) {        
            var branches = response.d;
            $('dropdownlist').empty();  
            $.each(branch, function(index, branches) {     
              $('dropdownlist').append('<option value="' + branch.ID + '" >' + branch.NAME + '</option>');

            });

          },

          failure: function(msg) {



          }

        });

      }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "EBService.aspx/getDepts",
                data: "{cid:" + reg + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("#<%=ddlCDept.ClientID%>").get(0).options.length = 0;
                        $("#<%=ddlCDept.ClientID%>").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select name", "0");
                        $("#lblDeptResult").addClass("loading");
                        var i = 0;
                        $.each(msg.d, function (index, item) {
                            $("#<%=ddlCDept.ClientID%>").get(0).options[$("#<%=ddlCDept.ClientID%>").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.c_dept_name, item.c_dept_id);
                            i = i + 1;
                        });

 [WebMethod]
    public static List<CDept_MstrBO> getDepts(int cid)
    {
        if (CDeptList == null)
        {
            CDept_MstrBO objDeptBo = new CDept_MstrBO();
            objDeptBo.companyID = 1;
            CDeptList = objDeptBo.getCDeptList(objDeptBo);
        }
        List<CDept_MstrBO> deptList = CDeptList.Where(d => d.c_id == cid).ToList();
        return deptList;

    }
```